# Sample code or Library or Tutorial to draw in iPad/iPhone using Quartz 2D

Tags: ios, graphics, quartz-2d

Is there an open source library or sample code to draw in iPad using quartz 2d? Or can you suggest any tutorials to the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this section of developer documentation on drawing in Quartz2d, I think it will fulfill your request
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html